# Frases terminadas em "sobre"

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Tenho ouvido e lido com frequencia frases terminadas em "sobre", e me parece que é algo relativamente recente.
Este tipo de construção está correta?

> – Qual a sua opinião do cinema contemporâneo? Vamos conversar sobre?

Ou o correto seria "… sobre isso", "… sobre este assunto", etc.?

Comment: Também notei e creio ser recente. Em exemplos como "Isso é uma coisa que temos que conversar sobre" (ao invés de "Isso é uma coisa sobre a qual temos que conversar.") me passou pela cabeça que poderia ser um anglicismo — "_That's something we have to talk about_" (por seu lado, também uma versão coloquial do mais formal "_That is something about which we have to talk._").

Comment: Standard não é. Se é recente ou não no Brasil não sei, mas lembra-me que no livro _Áreas Críticas da Língua Portuguesa_ já nos anos 90 os autores citavam exemplos (se bem me lembra em revistas de informática, mais propícias a anglicismos). A minha ideia é que nunca se generalizou muito.

Comment: @stafusa [de Lemos, Simone H., "Preposition Stranding in Heritage Speakers of Brazilian Portuguese" (2013). *FIU Electronic Theses and Dissertations.* 912.
https://digitalcommons.fiu.edu/etd/9](https://digitalcommons.fiu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2034&context=etd), e [também](https://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/myo507/Papers/Almeida&Yoshida_published.pdf).

Comment: Very nice finding, @tchrist . Will you have the time to write an answer? I probably won't.

Comment: @stafusa Probably not, at least not soon.

Comment: @tchrist Alright. Hopefully someone will come to it soon enough. If not, I'll try too.

Comment: Daniel, se você consultar as referências apontadas por tchrist e alcançar uma certa compreensão do tema, seria uma contribuição muito bem-vinda uma resposta sua a sua própria pergunta.

Comment: Excelentes referências, obrigado. Quando tiver um tempo vou ler com calma e escrever uma resposta

Comment: Preposition stranding is not a feature of Portuguese. Who are you talking to? Com quem você está falando, ou Você está falando com quem? Cutting to the chase, I don't see any sentences ending with a preposition, except in special circumstances like games: O livro foi de ? Resposta: de da Silva.

Comment: @Lambie não seria tão taxativo. No meu contacto com brasileiros é relativamente comum ouvir frases a acabar em "sobre", como refere o OP. Não duvido de que o fenómeno existe no Brasil, pelo menos entre as pessoas com quem tenho contacto (mineiros entre 25-40 anos, principalmente). Dito isto, não me parece que a sintaxe seja a mesma do inglês. A minha ideia é de que não são relativas como "temos coisas que temos de conversar sobre", mas simplesmente uma omissão de "isso" no final. Posso estar enganado, contudo

Comment: That thesis found by tchrist says this (which is basically what I said): **"Stranding the preposition is licensed in BP in rare cases of**, for example,
topicalization, as shown in (28) and illustrated in Figure 7: Isto, eu sou contra!" [My example was slightly different.]

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o artigo abaixo dá conta do que eu queria falar. Vou acrescentar: O português não tem o que se chama *preposition stranding* (sem objeto depois da preposição) que se ve em frases em inglês como: What were they talking about?
Só talvez em **certos diálogos** nos quais se poderia dizer:
Pessoa 1- O poema era do Fernando Pessoa.
Pessoa 2- O poema era de ? [subentendido: de quem?]
OU
Pessoa 1- Ela falou sobre a guerra civil americana.
Pessoa 2-Ela falou sobre ? [subentendido: o que?]

> #### Transitividade verbal e a preposição sobre
>
> Com que verbos podemos usar a preposição sobre?
>
> A preposição, como é sabido, serve para ligar dois elementos de uma
> oração, que, muitas das vezes, pode ser um verbo.
>
> Não é incomum nos depararmos com o uso das preposições de forma
> totalmente equivocada, por conta do fenômeno conhecido como
> anglicismo. Sim, por conta da tradução errônea da estrutura frasal do
> idioma inglês, passou a ser muito utilizada a expressão “é sobre
> isso”. Percebam que não há nenhum outro elemento que exija a ligação
> pela preposição sobre. É sobre, mas o que é sobre isso? Isso? Isso é
> sobre? Não faz nenhum sentido.
>
> **Da mesma forma é inconcebível o fenômeno das preposições ao final da
> frase, como por exemplo: “precisamos falar sobre”** (we need to talk
> about). Não seria estranho falar **“quero saber onde ela veio de”** (I
> want to know where she came from), ou “ele achou o livro que ele
> estava procurando por” (he found the book he was looking for).
>
> A insistência com a preposição sobre tem uma explicação: ela puxou a
> linha deste fenômeno que tem comprometido sobremaneira a clareza da
> exposição de ideias no nosso idioma. Deixando as péssimas traduções de
> lado, que retiram o sentido das frases, convém destacar que também não
> faz nenhum sentido utilizar preposição nos casos em que o verbo é
> transitivo direto.
>
> **A regra é muito óbvia: verbos transitivos diretos não pedem
> preposição.** Com base nesse raciocínio, não há como empregar a
> preposição sobre (sim, ela de novo) com os verbos estudar, falar,
> pesquisar, aprender, ler, porque são todos verbos transitivos diretos.
>
> Será que estamos prestando atenção na regência verbal quando
> construímos as orações? Estamos respeitando a transitividade dos
> verbos ou estamos seguindo tendências sem nenhum critério?
>
> Elaboração: Patrícia Corazza

[Transitividade e a preposição sobre](https://www.tjsc.jus.br/web/servidor/dicas-de-portugues/-/asset_publisher/0rjJEBzj2Oes/content/transitividade-verbal-e-a-preposicao-sobre) (ênfase minha).

E se os "jovens falantes" deixam o sobre

Comment: Dizer que "falar sobre algo" seja errado porque "falar" é verbo transitivo direto me soou errado. Fui pesquisar no Michaelis, e consta que todos os verbos citados no penúltimo parágrafo (estudar, falar, pesquisar, aprender, ler) podem ser transitivos diretos ou indiretos, então este artigo está ao menos parcialmente errado.

Comment: @DanielSerodio  O artigo está certíssimo. Lamento. O mais importante é que o portugues não tem stranded prepositions. What do you want to talk **about**? Você que falar **sobre o que**? Obviamente.

Answer (score -1):

“`Vamos`” é parte do predicado “`conversar sobre`”, com sujeito elíptico “`nós`” (“`Vamos`” se encontra conjugado na **3ª pessoa do plural**) e o verbo “`conversar`” tem como objeto... o quê? Vamos conversar `sobre` ***o quê***? Falta o objeto indireto ao qual o verbo “**conversar**” se refere. Construções semelhantes a essa infestam a língua, furtivas: é anglicanismo.

Parece-me desídia do autor ao compor o período, todavia, a língua é viva, e Deus sabe que coisas piores houveram de ser — em razão de seu uso contínuo — “canonizadas”   pelos lexicógrafos. Coisa boa, tal qual o `imexível` [de Magri](https://oprogressodetatui.com.br/nossa-li%C2%ADngua-nao-e-imexi%C2%ADvel/), ou quaisquer outros neologismos que seres humanos jovens conjuram, esses demoram a figurar no VOLP.

Às vezes se faz necessário criar nova palavra para a novidade, quando ela se manifesta, espontaneamente, na realidade e no pensamento. Mas há certa **intencionalidade** de tentar descrever a coisa nova. Já há palavras substantivadas, adjetivadas, só não sei se `averbalizadas`. Na genuína tentativa de comunicar o que o mar **faz**, pode-se dizer `marejar`. Basta começar pelas palavras primitivas e as mais complexas formar-se-ão naturalmente.

No caso em tela (ou *caos em tela*, como queiram), é apenas pessoa bilíngue implementando uma tradução livre do inglês:

> “*What's your take on the contemporary movie scene? Is it something you’d like to talk about?*”

Terminou em `sobre` (“*about*”). Que chique! Pronto, agora o brasileiro quer imitar! :D

Há quem dirá que a tradução correta é “*Do you wanna talk about it?*” Discordo: expressões como “*Can we talk about it?*”, “*Do you wanna talk about this?*” e “*I don't wanna talk about it*”, na língua inglesa, são largamente utilizadas no sentido de *conversar sobre algo sério* — realmente fazer uma mesa redonda em volta do negócio, ter aquela conversa desconfortável da qual se deseja ardentemente esquivar-se.

> O político conversou com o povo **sobre a nova medida provisória**.

Mais exemplos:

- Discorrer sobre esse tema;
- Conversar mais sobre esse assunto; (como bem disse o OP).
- Discutir sobre esse tópico;

TL;DR: Faltou o complemento verbal, mas a expressão foi empregada na oralidade, então, como eles dizem... “***isso é okay***”.

Comment: O português e inglês tem estruturas completamente diferentes. Em português não existe o fenomêno de preposition stranding. Essa pregunta me faz lembrar outra quando eu havia recem chegado aqui, sobre se o português tem ou não tem "phrasal verbs".  Credo. Se ve que a outra pesso que deu resposta não entendia "phrasal verb" .Veja só: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/are-there-phrasal-verbs-in-portuguese/5234#5234 //haha Gostei do teuL Que chique etc.

Comment: Queria dizer: pessoa e teu.